# App is not get connected to the NodeJS server , after a build successful in React Native

Tags: react-native

**Here is NodeJS , which shows No apps connected**

[image]

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

    configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + "0.66.5"
          }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } 
    }
}
```

**This I'm getting as a build success**

[image]

- I have tried the stuff's suggested by stack but app not get's connected to NodeJS server...

Comment: kill first terminal and try with npm start -- --reset-cache command

Comment: debug apk is installed in your emulator, open that application manually once

Comment: I have tried but  not worked ...